# Why does this HTTP 200 message appear on the bottom of html, php, css and js files?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Fri, 06 Nov 2009 00:35:42 GMT Server: Apache Content-Length: 0 Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100 Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Type: text/plain

What does that mean, and why does that text appear on bottom of ALL html, php, css and js files?

I am running a nph-proxy.cgi script.

Answer (score 2):

This is the head content from a HTTP response. HTTP 1.1 is the protocol, 200 Ok is the response code, and the rest are various pieces of information used by the browser.

As to why it's appearing in the bottom of your browsing, I've no idea.

You haven't really provided much information about your scenario, so please clarify:

- Are you seeing this when you *browse* to EVERY webpage on the internet (in which case, this should be asked over at [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com))

or

- Are you seeing this when other people browse to YOUR website? (In which case this is probably the correct place for it)